# Java Stream groupingBy csv without writing a class for saving rows

Tags: java, java-stream

I am having a CSV file like this:

```
Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, female (%),United Republic of Tanzania,2015,76.08978
Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, female (%),Zimbabwe,2015,85.28513
Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, male (%),Honduras,2014,87.39595
Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, male (%),Honduras,2015,88.32135
Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, male (%),Angola,2014,82.15105
```

And a class for saving a line from it:

```
public class Line {
    //Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, male (%),Angola,2014,82.15105
    private final String gender;
    private final String country;
    private final int year;
    private final Float prosent;

    public Line(String gender, String country, String year, String prosent) {
        this.gender = gender;
        this.country = country;
        this.year = Integer.valueOf(year);
        this.prosent = Float.valueOf(prosent);
    }    
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }    
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }    
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }    
    public Float getProsent() {
        return prosent;
    }    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%.5s",country) + ", " + year + ", " + String.format("%.2f",prosent);
    }
}
```

And I am grouping like this with `stream.collect(Collectors.groupBy....`

```
Stream<String> file = Stream.empty();
        try {
            file = Files.lines(Paths.get("lukutaito_lyh.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

Map<String, List<Line>> lista = file
.map(r -> r.split(","))
.map(r -> new Line(r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5]))
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.getGender()));
System.out.println(lista);
```

And I get this as expected:

```
{ female (%)=[Unite, 2015, 76,09, Zimba, 2015, 85,29],  male (%)=[Hondu, 2014, 87,40, Hondu, 2015, 88,32, Angol, 2014, 82,15]}
```

Could I do something like this? Without the trouble of writing class.

```
.map(r -> r.split(","))
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r[2]));
```

Comment: Why do you hate classes? They make your code _much_ better (more readable), among many other things.

Comment: Writing a class isn't a trouble but an improvement

Comment: I am studying the power of java-streams.

Comment: @Lasse this feels unrelated to Java Streams unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to process an arbitrary CSV line and you don't want to write a separate class for each line format you can create a class `CSVRecord` which will store the parsed values in a `Map` or a `List` instead of a fixed number of fields.

Take a look at [Apache `commons-csv`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html) which does it already:

```
Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    String columnOne = record.get(0);
    String columnTwo = record.get(1);
}
```

Do note that this approach will defer some errors that could be found during compilation to runtime so you want to have good tests.

Answer (score 1):

Using class is always a better option as suggested in comments.

With java-14, you can avoid the boilerplate code in POJO,

```
public record Line(String gender, String country, int year, Float prosent){}
```